# PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null) When I try to log in to my app

Tags: flutter, dart

I can succesfully run my app but every time I try to log in, I get this message:
[image]
Before the app completely stops working. I am doing this project with other people and most of them can log in just fine, but they don't seem to have a clue about this error either

I have already looked through all the other posts and tried to follow the advice. Hence, I have made sure my SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints are correct, as well as updated the google-services.json file. My support email is in my firebase, and my OAuth consent screen is already filled up. I have removed my debugkeystore and created a new one, and also updated google on my device.

This is my flutter doctor for reference:

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3086], locale en-               US)
> [√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
> [√] Chrome - develop for the web
> [√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.27)
> [√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
> [√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2)
> [√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.79.2)
> [√] Connected device (4 available)
> [√] Network resources